# no he podido que se generen select dinámicos - reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

buen dia necesito que se generen select dinámicos y deben funcionar de la siguiente forma: tengo un input equipos por grupo, además tengo un select que se llame equipos por grupo, entonces si por ejemplo coloco en input  equipos por grupos el valor de 10  en el select me debe aparecer en los 'option´del select para seleccionar del numero 1 al diez, por que hay 10 diez equipos por grupo, ahora en este select si selecciono algún numero por debajo de 10 que me parezca otro select mostrándome el restante de numero por ejemplo si en el primer select seleccione 3 en el segundo select me permita seleccionar el 4,5,6,7,8,9,10 y asi mismo que se genere otro select hasta que ya no hayan valores para seleccionar.

**He intentado hacerlo pero no he podido de hecho solo tengo el siguiente código pero cuando escribo el valor de 10 en el input me envia el mismo valor al select pero no me envia de 1 a 10 en los   como lo necesito.**

```js
import { useState } from 'react'

export default function App() {
    const [input, setInput] = useState()
    const [values, setValues] = useState([])

    const handleClick = event => {
        event.preventDefault()
        setValues([+input, ...values])
        setInput('')
    }

    return (
        <>
            <input placeholder='Equipos por grupo' value={input} onChange={event => setInput(event.target.value)} />
            <button onClick={handleClick}>Agregar Equipos por grupo</button>
            <hr />
            <br />
            <select name='tipo_cancha' class='form-control'>
                <option value='no' selected>
                    Equipos por grupo
                </option>
                {values.map((item, index) => (
                    <option key={index} value={item}>
                        {item}
                    </option>
                ))}
            </select>
        </>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No estoy muy seguro de haber entendido tu requerimiento al 100%, sin embargo basado en tu código, cree esta implementación que te puede ayudar a resolver tu problema

```
import { useState } from 'react'

export default function App() {

  const [input, setInput] = useState('')
  const [initial, setInitial] = useState(0)
  const [selects, setSelects] = useState([])

  const handleClick = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    if (input && !isNaN(input)) {
      setInitial(+input)
      setSelects([+input])
    }
    setInput('')
  }

  const handleResetClick = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    setSelects([])
  }
  
  const handleSelectClick = (event) => {
    console.clear()
    event.preventDefault()
    const options = event.target.value
    let newSelects = []
    if (options && !isNaN(options)) {
      newSelects = [+options, ...selects]
      newSelects = newSelects.filter((item, pos, arr) => !pos || item != arr[pos - 1])
      setSelects(newSelects)
    }
  }

  const getOptions = (options) => {
    let result = Array.from({length: options}, (_, i) => i + 1)
    if (options < initial) {
      result = Array.from({length: initial - options + 1}, (_, i) => i + options)
    }
    result.sort((item, pos) => item - pos)
    return result
  }

  return (
    <>
      <hr />
      <input placeholder='Equipos por grupo' value={input} 
              onChange={event => setInput(event.target.value)} />
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Agregar Equipos por grupo</button>
      <button onClick={handleResetClick}>Reiniciar</button>
      <hr />
      {selects.map((select) => (
        <>
          <br />
          <span>{select} - </span>
          <select value='no' onChange={handleSelectClick}>
            <option value='no' selected>
              Equipos por grupo
            </option>
            {
              getOptions(select).map((item, index) => (
                <option key={index} value={item}>
                {item}
                </option>
              ))
            }
          </select>
        </>
      ))}
    </>
  )
}
```

Te dejo un enlace donde probe la implementación https://codepen.io/sur97c-the-flexboxer/pen/powjPGx?editors=1010

Ojala te sirva

## ** **Update** **

Como te comente tu requerimiento inicial no es claro, trate de implementarlo lo mejor que pude, :-) jejeje, y el código que te puse es solo un **ejemplo** en el que te puedes basar para ajustarlo a tus necesidades específicas (no las conozco) te respondo conforme a lo que escribiste:

**cuando yo selecciono por ejemplo el 1 dentro de un select el siguiente select no debe cargar el 1 si no a partir del dos y asi con todos**

El metodo **getOptions** se encarga de controlar los elementos "options" que se muestran dentro de los dropdowns dinamicos "selects" aqui puedes modificar el elemento inicial, el final y su orden si fuese necesario, en tu caso si quieres que inicie en el siguiente necesitas que la linea de la funcion quede asi:

```
result = Array.from({length: initial - options}, (_, i) => i + options + 1)
```

**cuando selecciono el diez colocando el caso que sean diez números no mas vuelve y me carga todos los números y no debería cargar mas selects**

Si requieres que ciertos valores "ya seleccionados"
previamente no puedan volver a generar dropdowns, solo agrega la validación que requieras, el arreglo "selects" controla los dropdowns que se crean, su **orden** y las opciones que se mostraran dentro de ellos, entoncen dentro del metodo **handleSelectClick** que se encarga de crear los dropdwons, puedes modificar la condición por algo asi:

```
if (options && !isNaN(options) && !selects.some(option => option === +options)) {
```

**el orden como carga es un poco confuso ya que los selects deberían mostrarse al final cada vez que se vayan cargando**

Como te comente en el punto anterior, puedes controlar el orden del arreglo "selects" en la función **handleSelectClick** para que los dropdowns aparescan en el orden que quieras, para mostrarlos como quieras necesitas agregar un indice al arreglo, en lugar de almacenar solo numeros podrias lamacenar un objeto algo como [{index:0, options: 6}, ...] y puedes controlar el orden del index de los dropdowns, agregando al codigo algo asi:

```
newSelects = newSelects.sort((item, pos) => item.index - pos.index)
```

**el valor del input no deberia quitarse cuando le doy al boton**

Como te dije me base en tu codigo y tu tienes eso en tu implementación inicial, solo elimina la linea que limpia el estado cuando le das click

```
setInput('')
```

Como sea actualice el **ejemplo** lo puedes volver a checar en https://codepen.io/sur97c-the-flexboxer/pen/powjPGx, pero vuelvo a repetir es un **ejemplo** para que tu lo puedas modificar y/o usar para lo que necesitas

Comment: ya probe el codigo pero tiene algunos errors, cuando yo selecciono por ejemplo el 1 dentro de un select el siguiente select no debe cargar el 1 si no a partir del dos y asi con todos , ademas cuando selecciono el diez colocando el caso que sean diez números no mas vuelve y me carga todos los números y no debería cargar mas selects, también el orden como carga es un poco confuso ya que los selects deberían mostrarse al final cada vez que se vayan cargando y por ultimo el valor del input no deberia quitarse cuando le doy al boton.

Comment: y el valor que selecciono deberia mostrarse dentro del select y no afuera

Comment: te encargo si me puedes ayudar..

Comment: me puedes colaborar con lo que puedas?

Comment: en los selects cuando se generan no se ve el campos que se selecciono, te envio un video donde explico  en si lo que no he podido hacer youtu.be/6FFmM2xY0nw